# Метод join() не работает

Tags: python

```
import random

def create_pswrd():
    global password
    password = ''
    chars = '123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
    length = '8'
    list_chars = list(chars)
    random_chars = random.shuffle(list_chars)
    filter1 = ''.join(random_chars)
    print(filter1)

    for i in range(int(length)):
        password += random.choice(filter1)

create_pswrd()
```

выдаёт ошибку:

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Password Generator\bin\a.py", line 10, in create_pswrd
filter1 = ''.join(random_chars)
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: Метод shuffle() смешивает элементы списка на месте.

Comment: очень интересно почему в вас длина в виде строки а потом вы ее все равно конвертируете в число

Comment: @splash58, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: там проект, length длина которую введёт в поле entry, следовательно, её я конвертирую в число, но это отрывок

Comment: Вставлю 5 копеек:
в python есть модуль string, оттуда можно импортировать символы
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так лучше но в одну строчку и метод возвращает пароль а не меняет глобальную переменную что тоже лучше ,по умолчанию длина 8 .

```
def password_generator(lenght:int = 8):
    return "".join(random.sample('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM',lenght))
```

но есть проблема ,`random.sample` не работает с длинами больше длины колекции которую он получил

поетому другое решение `random.choices` дне можно задавать любую длину
здесь по умолчанию 64

```
def password_generator_(lenght: int = 64):
    return "".join(random.choices(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'), k=lenght))
```